# Data retrieved from database to Dropdown list. User selects option and then send that value to Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, drop-down-menu

Now I have been trying to figure out a way to insert a dropdown menu selection by a user on the web-interface into MySQL database table_2 using PHP. The problem is that the dropdown list items are retrieved from the MySQL database from another table_2. Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance! Below shows the code I am using.

```
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  $myDB = mysqli_select_db($con, "database");

  $sqlSELECT = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT disastergroup FROM disastergroups');

    if (isset($_POST['group']))
         {
               $group = $_POST['group'];
               $test = "SELECT disastergroupid FROM disastergroups WHERE disastergroup = '$group'";
               mysqli_query($con, $test);
               $test_store = "INSERT INTO events (groupid_FK) VALUES ($test);"
               mysqli_query($con,$test_store);
         }
    else
        {
            echo "An option must be selected!";
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Title of Page</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
            <body>
                <form action = "detailslog.php" method = "POST">

                    <label for="groups">Disasters:</label>
                        <select name = "groups">
                            <option value = "">Select...</option>
                            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlSELECT)):;?>
                            <option><?php $row1['disastergroup'];?></option>
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data">
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>
```

So what I want to do is take the user's selection from the options "groups" and use that value to get the ID of that value from the table disastergroups and then store that ID into the table "events" as a Foreign Key. This have been giving me hell to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting value in `$_POST['group']`?

Comment: @Akshay Yes I am. I checked by echo $_POST['group'] to the webpage and I see the selected choice.

Comment: Then what problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql_quer = mysqli_query($con, $test); 
$FK_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_quer); 
$test_store = "INSERT INTO events (groupid_FK) VALUES ($FK_id[disastergroupid]);" 
mysqli_query($con,$test_store);
```

This fixed my problem for anyone viewing this post!